# split string dates into list of multiple dates

Tags: python

I have the following list, I am trying to split the elements to multiple "dates" accordingly,I want to write a function to do it,I am not sure it regex is the way to go or `datetime`

```
x=["2- 7 MAY, 2020, 10-12 JUN, 2014","7 February, 2020, 6 February, 2020, 26 October, 2018","16 JUN, 2020, 24 JUL, 2020, 28 FEB, 2020, 15 SEPT, 2020, 8-11 MAY, 2023, 22 OCT, 2020","14 JUN, 2020"]

for i in x:
    temp=my_func(i)
    if len(temp)==1:
        date1=temp[0]
        date2=""
    elif len(temp)>=2:
        date1=temp[0]
        date2=temp[1]
    else:
        continue
    #rest of my code
```

here is the expected output of `my_func`

```
#my_func(x[0])=["2- 7 MAY, 2020", "10-12 JUN, 2014"]
#my_func([x[1]])=["7 February, 2020", "6 February, 2020", "26 October, 2018"]
#my_func(x[-1])=["14 JUN, 2020"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your examples,

```
import re
for i in x:
    temp =re.findall('\d.*?\d{4}',i)
#output
['2- 7 MAY, 2020', '10-12 JUN, 2014']
['7 February, 2020', '6 February, 2020', '26 October, 2018']
['16 JUN, 2020', '24 JUL, 2020', '28 FEB, 2020', '15 SEPT, 2020', '8-11 MAY, 2023', '22 OCT, 2020']
['14 JUN, 2020']
```

Answer (score 1):

Split the string with `','`. There are always even number of parts. 2 contiguous parts constitute a date. So just join up two parts to form a date string.

`re` is fine, but this should too:

```
>>> x = ["2- 7 MAY, 2020, 10-12 JUN, 2014","7 February, 2020, 6 February, 2020, 26 October, 2018","16 JUN, 2020, 24 JUL, 2020, 28 FEB, 2020, 15 SEPT, 2020, 8-11 MAY, 2023, 22 OCT, 2020","14 JUN, 2020"]
>>> result = []
>>> for s in x:
        parts = s.split(',')
        result.append([','.join(parts[i:i+2]).strip() for i in range(0,len(parts),2)])
>>> result
[['2- 7 MAY, 2020', '10-12 JUN, 2014'], 
 ['7 February, 2020', '6 February, 2020', '26 October, 2018'], 
 ['16 JUN, 2020', '24 JUL, 2020', '28 FEB, 2020', '15 SEPT, 2020', '8-11 MAY, 2023', '22 OCT, 2020'], 
 ['14 JUN, 2020']
]
```

Your `my_func` will be simply:

```
>>> def my_func(s):
        parts = s.split(',')
        return [','.join(parts[i:i+2]).strip() for i in range(0,len(parts),2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

global Varibale is used but the output is as you wanted it to be. 
The program depends on the way how you format the dates. But with this format it works fine.

```
dates=["2- 7 MAY, 2020, 10-12 JUN, 2014","7 February, 2020, 6 February, 2020, 26 October, 2018","16 JUN, 2020, 24 JUL, 2020, 28 FEB, 2020, 15 SEPT, 2020, 8-11 MAY, 2023, 22 OCT, 2020","14 JUN, 2020"]

def splitdates(date):
    if type(date) is int:
        tosplit = str(dates[date])
    else:
        tosplit = date
    month = ["J" , "j" , "f" , "F" , "m" , "M" , "A" , "a" , "s" , "S" ,"n" , "N" , "o" , "O" , "D" , "d"]
    for item, character in enumerate(tosplit):
        if character in month:
            for item2, character in enumerate(tosplit[item+1:]):
                if character.startswith(","):
                    for item3, character in enumerate(tosplit[item+item2+2:]):
                        if character.startswith(","):
                            global newdate
                            newdate.append(tosplit[:item + item2 + item3 + 3])
                            nextPart = tosplit[item + item2 + item3 + 3:]

                            if nextPart.endswith(";"):
                                newPart = nextPart
                                splitdates(newPart)

                            else:
                                newdate.append(tosplit[item+item2+item3+3:])
                                return newdate

                    newdate.append(tosplit[:item+item2+item3])
                    return newdate


for x in range(len(dates)):
    newdate = []
    print("Date: ",splitdates(x))
```

Output is:

```
Date:  ['2- 7 MAY, 2020,', ' 10-12 JUN, 2014']
Date:  ['7 February, 2020,', ' 6 February, 2020, 26 October, 2018']
Date:  ['16 JUN, 2020,', ' 24 JUL, 2020, 28 FEB, 2020, 15 SEPT, 2020, 8-11 MAY, 2023, 22 OCT, 2020']
Date:  ['14 JUN, 2']
```

Answer (score 0):

**This  is Simplest algorithm **

iterate over list pick one by one string  now iterate over string with split method 
pick two consecutive value add them and append into new list

```
x = ["2- 7 MAY, 2020, 10-12 JUN, 2014","7 February, 2020, 6 February, 2020, 26 October, 2018","16 JUN, 2020, 24 JUL, 2020, 28 FEB, 2020, 15 SEPT, 2020, 8-11 MAY, 2023, 22 OCT, 2020","14 JUN, 2020"]
for i in x:
     final_answer=[]
     f=i.split(',')
     j=0
     while(j<len(f)):
        final_answer.append((str(f[j]+f[j+1])))
        j=j+2
print(final_answer)
```

output

['2- 7 MAY 2020', ' 10-12 JUN 2014']

['7 February 2020', ' 6 February 2020', ' 26 October 2018']

['16 JUN 2020', ' 24 JUL 2020', ' 28 FEB 2020', ' 15 SEPT 2020', ' 8-11 MAY 2023', ' 22 OCT 2020']

['14 JUN 2020']